# what attribute do i have to use in my css to not have the underlining in my sidebar navigation menu?

Tags: html, css, attributes

hey guys i want my sidebar nav menu to not have the underlining i tried it with the text-decoration:none attribute and the list-style-type:none but nothing worked. everything worked the way i wanted it so far but i am not finding any solution to how to make the underlining of the link disappear. can someone help me out please?

```css
#sidebar {
  background-color: f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 560px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  top: 60px;
}
#sidebar_wrapper {
  background-color: f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 560px;
  float: left;
  top: 60px;
}
#sidebar ul {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 25px;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#sidebar li {
  font-family: monospace;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#sidebar ul li ul li a {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#sidebar_li ul {
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <div id="sidebar_wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li>HTML</li>
      <div id="sidebar_li">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="bilder.html">Bilder</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="tabellen.html">Tabellen</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="text.html">Text</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <li>CSS</li>
      <div id="sidebar_li">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="einbinden.html">Einbinden in HTML</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the style of your `a` elements with `text-decoration: none`

```css
#sidebar a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#sidebar a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#sidebar {
  background-color: f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 560px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  top: 60px;
}
#sidebar_wrapper {
  background-color: f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 560px;
  float: left;
  top: 60px;
}
#sidebar ul {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 25px;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#sidebar li {
  font-family: monospace;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#sidebar ul li ul li a {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#sidebar_li ul {
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <div id="sidebar_wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li>HTML</li>
      <div id="sidebar_li">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="bilder.html">Bilder</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="tabellen.html">Tabellen</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="text.html">Text</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <li>CSS</li>
      <div id="sidebar_li">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="einbinden.html">Einbinden in HTML</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```